# Type 'AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer' in Assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.5.7.123, .... ' is not marked as serializable

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to add tabs dynamically to my aspx page and I am getting this error as soon as I run the code.

Type 'AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer' in Assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.5.7.123, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e' is not marked as serializable.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Here is my code:

```
private void AddNewChapterToTheStory()
    {

        DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["Story"];
        ImageStoryline story = new ImageStoryline(appEnv.GetConnection());

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel tpStory = new AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel();
            tpStory.HeaderText = story.GetImageTextById(Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["imageStorylineId"].ToString()));
            tpStory.ID = i.ToString();
            tcCase.Tabs.Add(tpStory);
            PlaceHolder PlaceHolder1 = new PlaceHolder();
            // int id = dt.Rows[i]["imageStorylineId"].ToString().Length == 0 ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["imageStorylineId"].ToString());
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<iframe src='www.google.com'></iframe>"));

            tpStory.Controls.Add(PlaceHolder1);


        }


    }
```

Comment: Where is tcCase declared?  The error mentions TabContainer, so I'd look at any code mentioning tcCase.

Comment: tcCase is created in the aspx page...

Comment: Usually I've received that error when attempting to load a Control into ViewState or Session.

Comment: I am doing the same thing. I am loading the control into the viewstate. But I really really need to load it into viewstate or session..

Comment: Well, you can't, because they aren't Serializable.  The best option is to load any content you are putting into the TabContainer into ViewState or Session, then when you need to re-generate them, generate new TabContainer, and fill it with the content stores in VS or Session.